# ToLower in Array.Contains in Entity Framework Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

It seems that in EF Core's query like `myContext.Books.Where(b => new [] { "harry potter", "the lord of the rings" }.Contains(b.Title.ToLower()))` filtering part is not executed on sql server, no 'where' close is built. I'm using postgresql and npgsql driver, but I've checked that the same behavior is for ms sql server.
So, do you know if it's possible to built query which will generate sql where clause like this (for postgresql): 
`where lower(title) in ('harry potter', 'the lord of the rings')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting limitation EF Core SQL translation. Upto release 1.1.2 EF core assumed that in `Array.Contains(item)`, `item` would be member expression or `EF.Property` method call indicating property access. But in your case, you have a different method call because you are calling `ToLower()` hence EF Core fails to recognize the pattern and does not translate `Contains` to server.

Co-incidentally this limitation was removed while fixing a different [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6937).
Now EF Core translate `item` if possible. Since `ToLower()` is can be translated it works correctly and generate `IN` statement. That issue is fixed in 2.0.0-preview1. So it should be available in 2.0 release of EF Core.

I tested the query with nightly build of 2.0.0 of EF Core. Following is the generated SQL.

```
SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[Title]
FROM [Blogs] AS [x]
WHERE LOWER([x].[Title]) IN (N'harry potter', N'the lord of the rings')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your linq statement appears to be a little off for doing a loose matching is all.

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var contextMock = new List<Book>
      {
        new Book(1, "Harry Potter and The Sorcerer's Stone", "Fiction"),
        new Book(2, "Harry Potter and The Secret Chamber", "Fiction"),
        new Book(3, "Dune", "Fiction"),
        new Book(4, "The Lord of The Rings The Fellowship of the Ring", "Fiction"),
        new Book(5, "The Lord of The Rings Return of the King", "Fiction"),
        new Book(6, "A Brief History of Time", "NonFiction")
      };


      var wrong = contextMock.Where(x => (new[]{ "harry potter", "the lord of the rings" }).Contains(x.Title.ToLower())).ToList();
      var right = contextMock.Where(x => (new List<string> { "harry potter", "the lord of the rings" }).Any(y => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(y.ToLower()))).ToList();

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't help. As I wrote, I want EF to generate sql with `where lower(title) in ('harry potter', 'the lord of the rings')` but now it generates only `select ...  from ...` which cause fetching whole table and then does filtering in memory.

Comment: ???  EF does not generate queries unless you are overriding the T4 template.  Postgresql is just a flavor of database.  Unless you have some other npgsql is just a driver.  So without more data you are just presenting a predicate that WHERE EVER you are putting it is wrong for your intention of lose matching.   If it is generated somewhere you did not provide that detail.  I just saw the linq '.Where(b => ...)' and saw it was wrong for the intent.